# Magento2: Config data save using Custom Module

Tags: magento2, core-config-data, patch-data

I want to save encrypted value in `core_config_data` while setup upgrade without using `config.xml`. I am trying to use data patch file

> Vendor\Credentials\Setup\Patch\Data\AddData.php

```
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchVersionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\WriterInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Encrypted;
use Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface;


public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        EncryptorInterface $_encryptor,
        WriterInterface $configWriter
    )
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup=$moduleDataSetup;
        $this->_encryptor = $_encryptor;
        $this->configWriter = $configWriter;
    }



$this->moduleDataSetup->startSetup();
        $privateKey = $encrypted = $this->_encryptor->encrypt($value);
        $publicKey = $encrypted = $this->_encryptor->encrypt($value);
        $this->configWriter->save(self::XML_PATH_PRIVATE_API_KEY, $privateKey, $scope = ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT, $scopeId = 0);
        $this->configWriter->save(self::XML_PATH_ENABLED, 1, $scope = ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT, $scopeId = 0);
        $this->moduleDataSetup->endSetup();
```

But entry is not saving. I have checked patch table entry and here patch get register.

Comment: Could you please share the constructor function? I want to check configWriter variable definition.

Comment: I have updated the code above

Comment: I have checked with your sample code, it's working perfectly. Please check once values of self::XML_PATH_PRIVATE_API_KEY and self::XML_PATH_ENABLED variables.